# enviar e insertar varias registros ala vez desde android a php con volley

Tags: php, mysql, android

Buen dia soy novato en desarrollo en android

Tengo un problema con mi app de android. lo que hace es extraer los contactos del telefono e insertarlos en mysql atraves de php uso la libreria volley para enviar los datos, tengo un metodo que es el que realiza el envio a php nombre y telefono y en el onCreate realizo la extraccion de contactos y en el while itero el metodo de envio cada vez que recorro un contacto en ocasiones inserta bien pero solo 25 registros(faltan como 50) y aveces no inserta nada, al igual me manda un error com.android.volley.noconnectionerror java.net.socketexception cabe mencionar que el error lo manda en ocaciones pero aun asi cuando lo manda realiza la insercion en la base no se si se este saturando de tanto envio o que es lo que este sucediendo adjunto el codigo.

NOTA: algo q me parece extraño esque cuando instalo mi app no me da los permisos y no me los solicita se los tengo que dar manualmente desde el telefono.

archivo mainactivity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactos);

    Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    

    while(people.moveToNext()) {
        int nameFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
        String contact = people.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex);
        int numberFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
        String number = people.getString(numberFieldColumnIndex);

        texto.append(contact);
        texto.append(number);
        texto.append("\n");
        ejecutarServicio("https://**********",contact, number);


    }

}
private void ejecutarServicio(String URL, String nombres, String numeros){
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "operacion exitosa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parametros.put("nombre", nombres);
            parametros.put("numero", numeros);


            return parametros;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

}

archivo manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Contactos"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Tu código está pésimamente concebido. Estás llamando a `ejecutarServicio` una y otra vez desde este bucle: `while(people.moveToNext()) {`  si hay mil contactos, harás mil llamadas, si hay 5,000 contactos, 5,000 llamadas. Considera meter todo en un HashMap y luego llamar una sola vez a `ejecutarServicio` pasándole el HashMap con todos los contactos. Las llamadas a Volley son costosas, debes optimizar haciendo eso. Lo de los permisos es tema aparte, sugiero que abras una nueva pregunta para ello mostrando el mensaje de error que te muestra y lo que tienes en tu `Manifest`.

Comment: hola muchas gracias @A.Cedano por la respuesta y una disculpa por el codigo esque apenas me voy emergiendo en el mundo de la programacion aqui en la uni con respecto a lo que me comentaste de optimizar lo hize de esta manera en la parte donde lleno el hashmap parametros meti el while y para llenarlo pero ahora mi problema es que no se como recibirlo en php o como iterar todos los datos que contiene me ayudaria mucho me pudieras orientar muchas gracias

Comment: Si quieres que te ayudemos con PHP debes mostrar el código PHP que usas para recibir los datos. Además, debes mostrarnos cómo has creado el HashMap, sobre todo para saber qué claves pusiste en cada valor, pues deberás usar esas claves en PHP para obtener cada valor. Pulsa en [edit] para completar tu pregunta.

Comment: hola buen dia ya resolvi el problema en el while cuando lleno el hashmap cree un contador el cual lo anexe como clave cada vez que iteraba el ciclo y cuando terminaba mande tambien el contador con otra clave y ya en php obtenia el contador que en este caso traia el numero total de contactos y con un while y un contador realize la misma operacion iterar el ciclo y la variable post solo le mande el contador para que recuperara el valor y lo insertara en la base no se si fue la mejor manera pero ya me funciono y pude entregar la practica a tiempo muchas gracias por tu apoyo que tengas un buen dia